# Can any set of numbers be expressed by a function?

Tags: math, set, theory

Is it possible to express ANY random set of numbers by a function?

**Question clarification:**

for example:
if desired result set = {1,2,3,4,5}

so I don't mean something like this:

```
function getSet(){
   return {1,2,3,4,5};
}
```

but more like this:

```
function genSet(){
   result = {}
   for(i=0;i<5;i++){
     result.push(i);
   }
   return result;
}
```

So in other words, can there be a logic to calculate any desired set?

Comment: What is expressing a set of numbers by a function even supposed to mean?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about abstract mathematics, not programming.

Comment: Any finite set of numbers obviously can. f(0) = first number, f(1) = second numbert, etc.

Comment: Okay, the edit helps a bit, but it's still not clear what you mean by "a logic". There's no good way to draw a line between a "logical" way of generating a set and just encoding it directly. Also, what about infinite sets?

Comment: Well, say we take pi and make each digit an element of a set. Technically that is an infinite set that could be computed theoretically. But what about other sets? For example if I get a set {3,9,2,0,1,2,6,3,2,8,3} is there a efficient way to describe that set?

Comment: You're not going to get anything more efficient than a bitvector representation. At that point, every possible string of bits represents a set, and you've hit the information-theoretical limit. You can't have every set be produced by a short program, because there are only so many short programs.

Comment: Also, you seem to be mixing up sets and lists. Sets are unordered and can't contain multiple copies of an element.

Comment: Any `n`-element set can be generated by a polynomial of degree `n-1`

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Which has `n` coefficients, so really all you've gained are a bunch of powers of `x` written next to your numbers.

Comment: OP's stipulation doesn't exclude that. :) Clearly it is impossible to represent an arbitrary set of `n` bits with fewer than `n` bits.

Comment: In a partial defence of the question it is not just mathematics this sort of thing is the subject of theoretical computer science. The [cstheory stack](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place to ask this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of mathematics behind this question. There are some interesting results.

Any set of (real) numbers can be *define* by a polynomial function f(x) = a + b x + c x^2 + ... so that a number is in the set if f(x)=0. Technically this is an algebraic curve in 1D. While this might seem a optimistic result there is not limit on how complex the polynomial could be and polynomials above the degree 5 have no explicit result.

There is a whole field of study on [Computable numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number), real numbers which can be can be computed to within any desired precision by a finite, terminating algorithm, and their converse: *non computable numbers*, which can't. The bad news is there are a lot more non-computable numbers than computable ones.

The above has been based on real numbers which are decidedly more tricky than the integers or even a finite set of integers which is all we can represent by `int` or `long` datatypes. There is a big field of study in this see [Computability theory (computer science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computability_theory_%28computer_science%29). I think the Turings halting problem come in to play, this is about if you can determine if a algorithm will terminate. Unfortunately this can't be determined and a consequence is "Not every set of natural numbers is computable." The proof of this does require the infinite size of the naturals so I'm not sure about finite sets.

Comment: This is quite interesting, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

## Representations

There are two common representations used for sets when programming. Suppose the set S is a subset of some universe of items U.

### Membership Predicate

One way to represent the set S is a function `member` from S to { true, false }. For all x in U:

- `member(x) = true` if x is in S
- `member(x) = false` if x is not in S

#### Pseudocode

```
bool member(int n)
   return 1 <= n <= 5
```

### Enumeration

Another way to represent the S is to store all of its members in a data structure, such as a list, hash table, or binary tree.

#### Pseudocode

```
enumerable<int> S()
    for int i = 1 to 5
        yield return i
```

## Operations

With either of these representations, most set operations can be defined. For example, the union of two sets would look as follows with each of the two representations.

### Membership Predicate

```
func<int, bool> union(func<int, bool> s, func<int, bool> t)
    return x => s(x) || t(x)
```

### Enumeration

```
enumrable<int> union(enumerable<int> s, enumerable<int> t)
    hashset<int> r
    foreach x in s
        r.add(x)
    foreach x in t
        if x not in r
            r.add(x)
    return r
```

## Comparison

The membership predicate representation can be extremely versatile because all kinds of set operations from mathematics can be very easily expressed (complement, Cartesian product, etc.). The drawback is that there is no general way to enumerate all the members of a set represented in this way. The set of all positive real numbers, for example, cannot even be enumerated.

The enumeration representation typically involves much more expensive set operations, and some operations (such as the complement of the integer set {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}) cannot even be represented. It should be chosen if you need to be able to enumerate the members of a set, not just test membership.